# Typescript equality always false even though value is true

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd developed one simple typescript to compare the value passing from the drop down value.

Kindly see my code below

Even though the value = 'Supervisor', the selection always goes to else method.

```
updateFilter(value: string): void {
// value = 'Supervisor'
if (value === 'Supervisor') {
  this.loading = true;
  this._dashboardservice.getAllSupervisor().subscribe(
    resp => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.listofmodules = Module [resp.length];
      this.listofmodules = resp;
    }
  );
} else {
  this._nzMessage.create('error', 'Only Supervisor are allowed at the moment');
}}
```

But if i change the `===` to `==` . Everything is okay, but the IDE prompt me an error `== should be === tslint(triple-equals)`

Any advice is appreciate. Thank you stackoverflow.

**UPDATE**
Try a few more solution. To check whether it the same type or not. But still no luck. Kindly see updated code below

```
updateFilter(value: string): void {
console.log('Log value: ' + value);

let tempvalue: string;
tempvalue = 'Supervisor';

if (value === tempvalue) {
  this.loading = true;
  this._dashboardservice.getAllSupervisor().subscribe(
    resp => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.listofmodules = Module [resp.length];
      this.listofmodules = resp;
    }
  );
} else {
  this._nzMessage.create('error', 'Only Supervisor are allowed at the moment');
}}
```

Even the `console.log('Log value: ' + value);` showing `Log value: Supervisor`.

**2nd UPDATE**

I try to print the typeof for both value and tempvalue.

```
value = object
tempvalue = string
```

why is this happening ? In the beginning of my function, I already state that the `value: string`

Any idea ?

Comment: just to confirm , both are of same type?

Comment: if you are giving manually `value = 'Supervisor'` not from the drop down then also it goes to else part?

Comment: @ameruddinjamil `===` means exactly same value and `==` means similar to check your type of value and also check upper and lower case

Comment: @ashishpal if i give the value manually, it will go to if part. can you tell me why ?

Comment: @Abhishek so, which part of my code should I enhance ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I think they are not same type. that's explain why if fall into else part, but I dont know how to correct my code.

Comment: @ameruddinjamil try `if (value.toString === tempvalue){}`.

Comment: @ameruddinjamil also check value with any space or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to trim your string before passing to some condition.

```
value = value.trim();
tempvalue = tempvalue.trim();
```

---

For Debugging, you can use `escape()` function in angular to see whether you have extra characters or symbols or not(which are not shown in the output).

### Like:

```
console.log(escape(value));
```

**Example:**

```
'Supervisor\r'
```

Where, \r is carriage return will not be shown in the output as "\r". It will be shown as "Supervisor"
But, if I use `console.log(escape(value));` then it will be shown as:

```
Supervisor%0D
```

in console.log() function. So, I will get to know, that there are extra characters in string, which can be solved by `trim()` function in most cases.

---

### UPDATE:

Since, `value` variable is of object type, use `valueOf()` function to get string value from an object. Then you can compare.

```
value = value.valueOf();
```

Comment: Hi @Saddam Pojee, thank you for the reply. I am following your guide to using the .trim(). But in the console. it show an error which 'value.trim is not a function at classname.html' may i know why this is happen ?

Comment: @ameruddinjamil You have to write that `trim()` function in `.ts` file. In `updateFilter` function.

Comment: Hi @Saddam Pojee, I have an update. Apparently, the value typeof is Object. why is this happen actually ?

Comment: @ameruddinjamil That means when you are calling `updateFilter` function, you are passing it as an `object` instead of `string`. Try doing this in `updateFilter` function: `value = value.valueOf();`  or make sure you pass string and not object.

Comment: its actually I am passing an event. its like this updateFilter($event)

Comment: @ameruddinjamil Then use `valueOf()` function. It will solve your problem. I updated my answer.

Comment: Im using the simple solution.. value = value + '';

and its solve everything.. huhu.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are using value === 'Supervisor', a strict type coercion function, it will measure the value and the type to be true for it to be true. While == operator only compare the value, not type.

Check your 'value' type, whether it is a string or not. only if the value is also a string (same as tempvalue), then it will return true.

Comment: I tried print the typeof value. Apparently, the typeof is object and not a string. why is that happening is it ?

Comment: try to remove the ' : void ', and then check the type again

Comment: or, you can try this one.

let value:string;

updateFilter(value)